# Centering chapter titles

Tags: chapters

In the MWE below. What is the most convenient way to center the titles **Preface** and **Abstract**, rather than setting them flush left?

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}
\chapter*{Abstract}

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Body}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look to the _titlesec_ package.

Comment: You are talking of `centering` the titles horizontally, not both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Should centering be applied only to unnumbered chapter headings, or to all chapter headings?

Answer (score 18):

Since this about the `\chapter*` command for two titles (Abstract and Preface) only, it's sufficient to say `\chapter*{\centering Abstract}` etc. as command. This is grouped inside the internal command `\@makeschapterhead` -- it does not have a side effect on other implicitly used `\chapter*` commands, such as in `\tableofcontents`.

(The `\blindtext` as well as `Some text` aren't centered, so the `\centering` inside the `\chapter*` argument is safe, as long as no entry to the ToC is necessary (which is not the case, as we are talking about `\chapter*`)

If all `\chapter*` or `\chapter` titles should be centered horizontally, an `\xpatchcmd` approach is more useful. (See the edit at the bottom of this answer)

```
\documentclass{book}



\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{\centering Preface}
\blindtext

Some text
\chapter*{\centering Abstract}


\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Body}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

This code centers all chapter titles (regardless whether `\chapter*` or `\chapter`) **horizontally**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{%
  \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak%
}{%
  \Huge \bfseries\centering #1\par\nobreak%
}{\typeout{Patched makeschapterhead}}{\typeout{patching of @makeschapterhead failed}}


\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
}{%
  \huge\bfseries\centering \@chapapp\space \thechapter
}{\typeout{Patched @makechapterhead}}{\typeout{Patching of @makechapterhead failed}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}
\blindtext

Some text
\chapter*{Abstract}
\blindtext


\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext

Another text


\chapter{Body}
\blindtext

\chapter{Conclusion}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `\hfill` before and after to do the trick, however, titlesec package is also required

```
\phantomsection
\chapter*{\hfill{\centering Certificate}\hfill}
```

Full working example

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%optional
%titlesec is also required with these commands
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter*{\hfill{\centering Certificate}\hfill}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't centre the chapter heading; it's flush right. Also, it requires some work if you have headings that carry the `\chapter*` title, as well as writing stuff to the ToC.

Comment: I have tested it, it works for me that's why I have shared it.

Comment: I tried [this example code](https://pastebin.com/raw/MMn25cS9) and obtained a flush right chapter title.

Comment: Share the code so we can replicate your error then we might help.

Comment: Without `hyperref`: [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/MMn25cS9); with `hyperref`: [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/PyFJRJkb)

Comment: thanks for pointing, I have updated my previous answer,
looks like it also requires titlesec package 
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%optional
%titlesec is also required with these commands
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter*{\hfill{\centering Certificate}\hfill}
\end{document}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked with me

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} 
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

from the link below

[centering a chapter title](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5924)

Answer (score 0):

adjust thesis title page centering:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NDqLSW9KEw

Comment: Please add a meaningful [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).
Don't just link to external pages containing the LaTeX code.
External links can become invalid or inaccessible, and the answer could lose any value to future visitors. It's also much easier to use code typed out properly rather than in a youtube video

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simple approach to center all chapter titles by default, compared to the answer from user31729:

```tex
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\centering \normalsize \huge  \color{black}}{\thechapter}{10pt}{}
```

Now,

```tex
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae}
```

produces

[image]

and

```
\chapter{Curriculum Vitae}
```

produces

[image]