# Centering chapter number and title

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm new to latex and I've been experimenting on some.

This question is kind of similar to this [Centering chapter titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246804/centering-chapter-titles), but it only centers the chapter title. (I tried using `\chapter*{\centering Title}`, but this removes chapter number and only centers the "Title".)

I also tried `\chapter{\centering Title}`,  but this gives me an error:

```
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

Am I missing something?
If you need elaboration, I could reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage to do it using the `\titlesec` package in order to print the chapter centered with the title.

Try adding these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}               
\titleformat{\chapter}
 {\huge\bfseries\centering}
 {\thechapter}
 {10pt}
 {}
```

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}               
\titleformat{\chapter}
 {\huge\bfseries\centering}
 {\thechapter}
 {10pt}
 {}

\begin{document}


\chapter{title}


\end{document}
```

Obviously you can add other options to change the appearance of the title.

EDIT:

here is an MWE for centering a title on two lines:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\huge\centering}
{Chapter \thechapter}    %  <------ "\thechapter" is chapter number, it is preceded by the text you want to insert berfore chapter number, i.e. "Chapter"
{0ex}
{
  \vspace{1ex}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering}
[\end{minipage}]

\begin{document}


\chapter{Your title}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This gave "1 Title". How about "Chapter 1 \\ Title"? Note: \\ means end line. My document class is report.

Comment: So you could use a minipage: see the MWE in the modified post

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code, using the `display` style (chapter number and title on separate lines and the 3rd argument is a distance which for this style is the vertical distance between chapter number and chapter title. I also made the chapter title page header and footer empty, as is traditional in typography. The centring is obtained with the `titlesec` directive `\filcenter`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\filcenter}
{\huge\chaptername~\thechapter} %
{6ex}
{\Huge\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Looking-Glass House}

\end{document}
```

[image]