# Chapter title on center of page on multicolumn document

Tags: macros, formatting

I want it so when I call \chapter, the title of the chapters appears in the middle top of the page of a two column document made with the multicol package, is this possible?  if not, would it be possible to made so, when i call \chapter, the title doesn't appear in the main body of the page but only on a specially defined header?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246804/centering-chapter-titles or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539329/centering-chapter-number-and-title