How to use psvectorian package for writing a thesis in overleaf?
dear StackeExchange community,
I'm currently writing my thesis with latex since it's an elegant and beautiful language.
While looking for fancy chapter heading, I came across the psvectorian package.
I want to put an ornament under chapter 1 and above the chapter title like on this example
Styling Part page with psvectorian
here is my code:
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
           \usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
            \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
            \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
            %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
            %\usepackage{lmodern} % font typefaces
            \usepackage{epigraph} %quoting
            \usepackage{nomencl}
            \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
            \usepackage{csquotes}
            \usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
            \usepackage[english]{babel}
            \usepackage{psvectorian}
            \usepackage{pstricks}            
            \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
           
           
           \title{Thesis\\
           {\large university of ...i}}
            \author{author name}
            \date{2024}
            
            
            \begin{document}
            
            \maketitle
            
            \chapter*{Abstract}
        
            A thesis about ...
            
            \chapter*{Dedication}
            I dedicate this work to... 
            
            \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
            
            
            I want to thank...
            
            \tableofcontents
            \listoffigures
            
            \chapter{ state of art }
        
        
        \renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}
        \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
        
        \epigraph{\enquote{\textit{a quote.}}}{\textit{--- Author name.}}
        
       \section{Introduction}

    \chapter{ methodology }

\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}
        \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
        
        \epigraph{\enquote{\textit{a quote.}}}{\textit{--- Author name.}}

           \section{Introduction}
         
            
            \end{document}

I tried to do it with several codes but nothing works, is there a simple way for it please.

You would make it much more convenient for users willing to help you, if you would show a short, but compilable test document in your question. This way users wouldn't have to puzzle together all the pieces.

off-topic: don't load inputenc. if you're using \hspace{0.3em} to get paragraph indents after section headings, don't. load indentfirst instead.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you for yur answer , I tried a lot of code lines , and it ended up with the same error Your command was ignored.
Type  I    to replace it with another command,
or    to continue without it.

@cfr thank you for the advise, I'm a beginner in  overleaf, I generally uses lyx

the point is that you've given us a bunch of fragments of code. in order to help you, somebody has to try to stitch those fragments together into something they can compile. you can help people to help you by providing a coherent example. it is ok if it produces an error, if the error is what you are asking about.

for example, even if I patch your snippets together, \include{Chapter0/chapter0} will give me an error because no such directory or file exists on my machine. (and if it did, it wouldn't be the same chapter0.tex you're using.)

ok I will edit my question thank you for the comments

Run it with lualatex then you do not need the auto-pst-pdf package:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{epigraph} %quoting
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{pstricks}            

\title{Thesis\\
    {\large university of ...i}}
\author{author name}
\date{2024}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \chapter*{\psvectorian[scale=0.25]{2}Abstract\psvectorian[scale=0.25]{2}}
    
    A thesis about ...
        
\end{document} 



Thank you so much for your answer , is there a way to display the vectorian symbol under chapter 1  but above the chapter 1 title  all centered. for example:  chapter 1  -> ornament in the middle->title of the chapter  all at the center of the page  and the content  of the chapter (introduction...)  .... will be shown  on a newpage

for example: \chapter[First title]{\tabular{c}\psvectorian[scale=0.25]{2}\\First title\endtabular}. You need the optional argument for the table of contents.

thank you so much for your answers , is there a way to make the chapter title in the middle of the page so that the introduction will be automatically displayed on the next page because it is still on the top of the page.                                                    and also I have a long chapter title which is going out of the right side of the page . how can I fix that

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246804/centering-chapter-titles
